# How to maintain Cluster map index order same as my DataFrame index order

Tags: python, dataframe, plot, heatmap

I am trying to plot a cluster map with python Sea-born package

I want the row order of heat map same as DataFrame index order

But the image seems not

my data have some character like :

data['character']= ['A','A','A','B','B','C','C']

I use the color bar to show the character

If the order of the cluster map is the same order as my data frame

Same character with be together in my color bar

But it is not

What can I do to make the cluster map order same as the data frame index order

THANKS a lot

Comment: Any updates on this question? I am having a hard time maintaining column order.

Answer (score 0):

`seaborn.clustermap` has two boolean [keyword arguments](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.clustermap.html) `row_cluster=` and `column_cluster=` which can be set to `False`, which should disable clustering that axis.

You also can use `seaborn.heatmap` to generate a heat map without doing any clustering or changing the order of rows and columns. This is probably more efficient since it skips the clustering steps and goes straight to plotting a matrix.